# Не найдены jar файлы в tomcat/lib

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, servlet, jax-ws

Мне нужно сделать веб сервис на jax-ws. Я добавил его jar файлы в tomcat9/lib. В итоге при запуске все равно ругается, что нет таких то файлов (там не только эти, их было больше, я скопировал только про самые первые). Tomcat9 рабочий, я проверял на запуске обычного servleta. Если не хватает еще данных для анализа, напишите в комментариях, я добавлю. Или можно скооперироваться в другом месте для большего удобства.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!!!

**Errors tomcat9:**
    29-Apr-2017 10:31:37.484 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/D:/IdeaProjects/WS/tomcat9/lib/hk2-core.jar] from classloader hierarchy
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IdeaProjects\WS\tomcat9\lib\hk2-core.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)

```
    29-Apr-2017 10:31:37.515 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/D:/IdeaProjects/WS/tomcat9/lib/config.jar] from classloader hierarchy
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IdeaProjects\WS\tomcat9\lib\config.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)

    29-Apr-2017 10:31:37.530 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/D:/IdeaProjects/WS/tomcat9/lib/auto-depends.jar] from classloader hierarchy
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IdeaProjects\WS\tomcat9\lib\auto-depends.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)

    29-Apr-2017 10:31:37.530 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/D:/IdeaProjects/WS/tomcat9/lib/javax.inject.jar] from classloader hierarchy
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IdeaProjects\WS\tomcat9\lib\javax.inject.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)

    29-Apr-2017 10:31:37.546 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/D:/IdeaProjects/WS/tomcat9/lib/hk2-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IdeaProjects\WS\tomcat9\lib\hk2-api.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)

    29-Apr-2017 10:31:37.562 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/D:/IdeaProjects/WS/tomcat9/lib/tiger-types.jar] from classloader hierarchy
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IdeaProjects\WS\tomcat9\lib\tiger-types.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)

    29-Apr-2017 10:31:37.562 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/D:/IdeaProjects/WS/tomcat9/lib/bean-validator.jar] from classloader hierarchy
     java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\IdeaProjects\WS\tomcat9\lib\bean-validator.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)
```

**Servlet:**

```
import server.service.HelloWebService;
import server.service.HelloWebServiceImplService;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // подключаемся к тегу service в wsdl описании
        HelloWebServiceImplService helloService = new HelloWebServiceImplService();
        // получив информацию из тега service подключаемся к самому веб-сервису
        HelloWebService hello = helloService.getHelloWebServiceImplPort();

        // обращаемся к веб-сервису и выводим результат в консоль
        String helloString= hello.getHelloString("Vladislav");

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print("<h1>" + helloString + "</h1>");
    }
}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>vkuznetsov</groupId>
  <artifactId>ChallengeClient</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ChallengeClient Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.war.version>3.0.0</maven.war.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>ChallengeClient</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
          <configuration>
              <source>${jdk.version}</source>
              <target>${jdk.version}</target>
              <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven.war.version}</version>
          <configuration>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил вместо девятой версии tomcat поставить седьмую. Запустил через админку и задеплоил серверную и клиентскую часть. Дополнительные jar не требовал.

Поэтому итог: используйте tomcat таким образом. Скачиваете, распаковывайте. Указываете пользователя админа для него. И запускаете. А war закидываете в webapp.